# Finding components of a circle.

Tags: circles

I'm working on some summer problems so that I can be more prepared when I go into my class in the fall. I found a website full of problems of the content we will be learning but it doesn't have the answers. I need a little guidance on how to do this problem.

The following diagram shows a circle with centre *o* and radius 5 cm.
[image: picture of circle]
The points **A**, **B**, and **C** like on the circumference of the circle, and $\angle AOC$ = 0.7 radians.
a. Find the length of the arc *ABC*.
b. Find the perimeter of the shaded sector.
c. Find the area of the shaded sector.

For a, the arc length would be the angle multiplied by the radius, correct?

*l* = 5 x 0.7
*l* = 3.5 cm

For b, would it be 2 radii and the length of the arc added together?
5+5+3.5 = 13.5 cm

And for c, I’m honestly not too sure. Is it the central angle over 360° = the sector over $πr^2$

Comment: We can use the fact that the area is proportional to the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point $a$ and $b$ your answers are correct.

For the area we have that for the whole circle

- $A(2\pi)=\pi r^2=\frac12 \cdot 2\pi\cdot r^2$

therefore for an angle $\theta$ since the area is proportional to the angle

- $A(\theta)=\frac12 \theta r^2$

with $\theta$ expressed in radians.

Comment: Using this formula, I entered A = 1/2 x 0.7 x $5^2$ and got 8.75$cm^2$ as my answer. Does this sound right?

Comment: @Ella Yes exactly that's correct!